# How to encrypt, decrypt data using DUKPT and 3DES algorithm in iphone for a card reader application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, 3des

I have reffered this [code](https://github.com/mburshteyn1/DUKPT/blob/master/DUKPT.m) and successfuly created IPEK and PEK for differant TKSN and Now how do I encrypt this keys to my card reader device and how do decrypt the card information using those keys. In fact I'm not familiar  with the DUKPT techniques and I was so new to that.Any suggestions will be appreciated

---

**Note :**
I have BDK and Final TKSN values how do I encrypt and decrypt these values in my device ?

Comment: how did u get ur BDK number

Comment: @Ruban Did you figure out how to get the BDK from the two "Key Component" values?

Comment: @mdimarcaThe Card Reader Provider(Magtek) asked me to pay for each decryption. So we did not use this provider.

Answer (score 1):

Searching on the same thing and I found this example library on github: https://github.com/mburshteyn1/DUKPT

I haven't tried it myself yet but it takes BDK and KSN as input which you have.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but could be a comment.

Comment: Did you end up getting that library to work? I've been trying it to no avail so far